# js regex - Does ^ have special meaning "at the start of a group" ()?

Tags: javascript, regex

I was reading [this page from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) and the section about `^`says:

> This character has a different meaning when it appears at the start of
> a group.

But I can't find any info on the linked page. What different meaning could it have? The potential to do OR operations like `(^|_)a`, which means either an `a` at the start of the string or right after an `_`?

Or perhaps it should say `at the start of a character set`, ie `[^asdf]` instead?

I'm pretty comfortable with regexes in general, just thrown off by this statement.

#### UPDATE:

RE: comments with definitions of `^` and close votes: I'm very familiar with the caret operator. This is a question about the wording in the MDN docs. Just wondering if there was a hidden corner of the syntax I was unaware of.

I think @Barmar's comment is correct, if someone feels like getting some answer points.

Comment: `(^)` asserts position at start of a line. `[^]` negates a set of characters.

Comment: Follow the link at the URL you sent. `^` indicates either the beginning of the line OR a negation operator https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges#Types

Comment: When an unescaped `^` is outside character class, it is always "start of a string/line". Whether it is in a capturing group or not is not relevant. You just misunderstood the MDN reference which is just badly worded.

Comment: MDN calls `[abc]` a group, this is what it's referring to. You'd see this if you click on the [group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) link.

Comment: https://regexper.com/#%2F%28%5E%7C_%29a%2F

Comment: @Barmar, I suppose that is really the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MDN is using confusing, non-standard terminology. If you follow the [group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges) link, it goes to the page titled **Groups and ranges**, and it describes the `[...]` syntax. It's not referring to capture groups.

A `^` at the beginning of `[...]` inverts the sense of the match.